# Migrate/import Gmail calendar to new Gmail user account?

Tags: google-calendar

Can I migrate (import?) my calendar from an old Gmail account to a new Gmail account? I have a new user id.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can. You have to export the calendar(s) from your old account and then import it/them to the new account.

To export the calendar(s):

> Exporting content from a **specific calendar**
>
> Follow these steps to export one of your calendars:
>
> 1. In the calendar list on the left side of the page, move your mouse over the calendar you'd like to export from.
> 2. You'll see a drop-down arrow appear next to the calendar name. Click the drop-down arrow and select **Calendar settings**. (Alternatively, click the drop-down arrow next to **My calendars** and select **Settings**, then click the appropriate calendar from the list.)
> 3. Click the **ICAL** button in the 'Private Address' section at the bottom of the page, and click the displayed URL.
> 4. Save the exported file to the desired folder on your computer.

Or

> Exporting content from all calendars in your 'My calendars' list
>
> Here's how you can export all the calendars in your **My calendars** list at once:
>
> 1. Click the drop-down arrow next to **My calendars** and choose **Settings**.
> 2. On the Calendar Settings page, click the **Export calendars** link at the bottom of the **My Calendars** section. Keep in mind that you won't be able to bulk export calendars in your Other Calendars list (for example, public calendars you've added to your list, shared calendars with 'view' access only, etc.)
> 3. In the resulting compressed folder, you'll see an ICS file for each of the calendars you have permission to 'Make changes and manage sharing' for.

From [here](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37111&topic=1672003&ctx=topic).

Now, to import the calendar(s):

> To import events from iCalendar or CSV files, just follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click the down-arrow next to **Other calendars**
> 2. Select **Import calendar**
> 3. Click **Choose file** and find the file that contains your events, then click **Open**.
> 4. Select the Google Calendar where you'd like to import events, then click **Import**.
>
> Please note that recurring events may not be recognized when importing events from CSV files. In this case, individual items will be created for recurring events that fall between the dates you've selected.

From [here](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37118&topic=1672003&ctx=topic).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to move your calendars, then yes the answer above will work, but you need to be careful since it will not save your Shared calendars!

If you're looking for a sort've all inclusive transfer that will do Calendar (created and shared events), Gmail, Drive, Contacts, then I would actually suggest [G-transfer](https://www.g-transfer.com/) because I needed to move my entire account, just calendars.

Unfortunately Google makes migration in piecemeal.

Comment: Hi Sydney.  I notice that you and perhaps a few of your colleagues are promoting this product in various answers.  While it does provide an answer the questions in most cases, we tend to frown upon these subtle promotions of products, particularly when a pattern arises.  I would ask that you disclose any affiliation with the product in your answer and refrain from using answers as a means of promotion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Allow public access to every calendar you want to migrate
2. Send each one to a folder on your desktop e.g C:\Desktop\Google Calenders
3. Then log into your new google account and import each one as as a csv. file.
4. Once you do that, remember to go back to your old gmail and remove the public access.